# Associations and collections with Roar

Tags: ruby, rest, mongoid

Assume we have something like:

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :users
  field :name, type: String
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :company
  field :name, type: String
end

module CompanyRepresenter
  include Roar::Representer::JSON 
  property :name
end

module UserRepresenter
  include Roar::Representer::JSON 
  property :name
  link :self do
    user_url
  end
end
```

Then we go on to do something like this:

```
user.extend(UserRepresenter).to_json
```

And everything is just great. But how about:

```
User.all.to_json
```

or:

```
company.extend(CompanyRepresenter).users.to_json?
```

or even:

```
company.users.collect{|u| u.extend(UserRepresenter)}.extend(Representable::JSON::Collection).to_json
```

The result is always an array of Mongoid's normal `to_json` entries.

The question is how do I get something like `Company.all.to_json` to have Roared JSONs including the links and other extra serialization data.

Comment: The question is how do I get something like Company.all.to_json to have Roared json's with the links and all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out this is simple to achieve using [Representable](https://github.com/apotonick/representable) (which is used by Roar):

```
require 'roar/representer/json'

module PostRepresenter
  include Roar::Representer::JSON

  property :id
  property :title
end

require 'representable/json/collection'

module PostsRepresenter
  include Representable::JSON::Collection

  items extend: PostRepresenter
end

Post.limit(10).extend(PostsRepresenter)
```